# Associating a integer to string in a vector C++

Tags: string, c++11, vector, integer, double

I have a vector  Type which contains 100 values: [ 'City', 'Town', 'City', 'City',......, 'Town']

I want to associate/ map each of the string's in this vector with an integer/ double 10 and 20.

My attempt at the same:

```
int s = 20;
int o = 10;
for (int q = 0; q < 100; q++) {
    if (Type[q] == 'City') {
        'City' == s;
    }
    else (Type[q] == 'Town'){
        'Town' == o;
    }
}
```

This does not work. I would appreciate any help on the topic.

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there a way to map numbers to string though? I must also mention, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::map<std::string, int>` (or `std::map<std::string, double>`) like this:

```
    std::vector<std::string> Type = { "City", "Town", "City", "City", "Town" };
    std::map<std::string, int> m;

    int s = 20;
    int o = 10;
    for (size_t q = 0; q < Type.size(); q++) {
        if (Type[q] == "City") {
            m["City"] = s;
        }
        else if (Type[q] == "Town") {
            m["Town"] = o;
        }
    }
```

You'll get a map with two values:

> { "City": 20 }, { "Town": 10 }

If you want to have pairs or type and number you can use vector of pairs or tuples:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int>> tuples(Type.size());

int s = 20;
int o = 10;
for (size_t q = 0; q < Type.size(); q++) {
    if (Type[q] == "City") {
        tuples[q] = std::make_tuple("City", s);
    }
    else if (Type[q] == "Town") {
        tuples[q] = std::make_tuple("Town", o);
    }
}
```

You'll get a vector with values:

> {"City", 20 }, {"Town", 10 }, { "City", 20 }, { "City", 20 }, {"Town", 10 }